# Get data from DAO once time with ViewModel pattern RoomDatabase

Tags: android, android-room

I have an app where I use library **Room Persistence Library**.

Now I have this problem:

I have in my **ViewModel**:

```
public LiveData<List<Code>> getAllCodes() {
   return codeRepository.getAllCodes();
}
```

In my **codeRepository**:

```
public LiveData<List<Code>> getAllCodes() {
   return appDatabase.codeDao().getAll();
}
```

In my **DAO**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM codes ORDER BY id DESC")
LiveData<List<Code>> getAll();
```

So in my activity I can do this:

```
codeViewModel.getAllCodes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Code>>() {
   @Override
   public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Code> codes) {
      adapter.addItems(codes);
   }
});
```

And It works, but now, in another activity, I call a function where I need call RoomDatabase get all codes and creates a CSV.
My problem is that I do this:

```
 download_csv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       codeViewModel.getAllCodes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Code>>() {
          @Override
          public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Code> codes) {
             download(codes);
          }
       });
     }
 });
```

But **every time the code model is added on my db It call download**.
So how can I get once time data from my Database?
Should I create a second function that return simply List or is there a more clean way?

Comment: why don't you try to get codes outside the onclick? Define a variable to save the codes and since you have the observer set, then whenever you call the codes variable then it will always have the most recent version of the list

Comment: To be honest, I didn't get what is your issue here, could you try to explain into a different way? Do you want to export your data?

Comment: @joao86 yes, it can works, I'll try!

Comment: @BrunoDiegoMartins yes, I want export my data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to observe the `LiveData` in the second case, because that would cause the method `download()` to be invoked every time the codes are updated.

If all you want to do is to invoke `download()` when the user clicks on the button, then do this:

```java
download_csv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        List<Code> codes = codeViewModel.getAllCodes().getValue();
        if (codes != null) {
            download(codes);
        }
    }
 });
```